# Uma palavra que signifique "a dona do pedaço"

Tags: significado, expressões, substantivos

Estou procurando um substantivo que defina o significado da expressão "a dona do pedaço". Não assisto a novelas e, portanto, não tenho a idéia de seu significado preciso na trama televisiva, mas é óbvio que tem um sentido figurado.  Imagino que seja algo do tipo "a rainha da cocada preta", ou "aquela que exige deferência e obediência", ou "aquela que se julga (e age como se fosse) superior aos outros, seja pela força, poder ou beleza".

Não estou a procura de gíria ou de uma figura de linguagem.  Procuro um substantivo, simples ou composto, que defina exatamente a expressão citada, e que seja compreendida por qualquer falante da língua portuguesa.  A palavra seria usada na seguinte frase: "quem ela pensa que é?  Uma/A ___________.

MODIFICAÇÃO - A frase que postei acima foi uma escolha ruim, pois só dá margem a palavras com sentido figurado, e não é isso o que eu procuro.  Modifico para: "Depois de alguns dias convivendo com ela, percebi que tratava-se de uma ___________." ou "... cheguei a conclusão de que ela era uma/a
 _________."  Preferência para uma única palavra, se existir.

Comment: Uma rainha? Me parece o mais óbvio.

Comment: Entendo como "aquela que exige deferência e obediência", ou simplesmente "quem manda". Que tal "minha/nossa *chefe*"?

Comment: @Lambie  fiz uma modificação no post original.

Comment: @stafusa  Fiz uma modificação no post original.

Comment: Só acho uns com cara de adjetivo: soberba, arrogante, convencida, metida, desvanecida, presunçosa, pretensiosa, ... talvez "prima-dona"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pede-se "Uma palavra que signifique 'a dona do pedaço'" com o significado de "aquela que exige deferência e obediência", ou "aquela que se julga (e age como se fosse) superior aos outros, seja pela força, poder ou beleza".

Nesse sentido, entendo que pode-se usar o substantivo

- mandona: *aquela que manda com arrogância* (segundo o [Dicionário Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/mand%C3%A3o/)).

**Exemplo:** *A chefe era uma mandona incorrigível* (extraído do [Dicionário UNESP](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=RFrCN3hCsHoC&pg=PA454&dq=%22dono+do+peda%C3%A7o%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVxsnj-e_lAhURAtQKHdYBDmQQ6AEIKTAA#v=snippet&q=mandona&f=false)).

Por outro lado, "Uma palavra que signifique 'a dona do pedaço'" no sentido de "quem controla" (acepção trazida pelo [Dicionário UNESP](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=RFrCN3hCsHoC&pg=PA454&dq=%22dono+do+peda%C3%A7o%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVxsnj-e_lAhURAtQKHdYBDmQQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22dono%20do%20peda%C3%A7o%22&f=false)), pode ser o substantivo

- controladora

E entendendo "dominar" como sinônimo de "controlar", obtemos um terceiro substantivo possível:

- dominadora

Para estes dois últimos casos, exemplos similares ao primeiro podem ser construídos.

*Observações:*

1. Os três termos também podem ser utilizados como adjetivos.
2. Entendendo "quem controla" como "chefe, cabeça, líder" pode-se, ainda, usar o substantivo "[manda-chuva](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=RFrCN3hCsHoC&pg=PA454&dq=%22dono+do+peda%C3%A7o%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVxsnj-e_lAhURAtQKHdYBDmQQ6AEIKTAA#v=snippet&q=manda%20chuva&f=false)".

Comment: Você poderia expandir sua resposta, acrescentando definições para cada uma das sugestões, exemplos em contexto para caracterizar se são adjetivos ou substantivos, e links para referências?

Comment: @Centaurus Editei a resposta. Espero que tenha melhorado.